# Flutter PDF Rotation

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I use this package (https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) to create PDF files with app.. Now I can't find a way to rotate the page of PDF.

Comment: https://issueexplorer.com/issue/syncfusion/flutter-examples/396

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
    pageTheme: pw.PageTheme(
    // this set the orientation of the content of the page, not the page itself which confuses most people.
    orientation: pw.PageOrientation.landscape,
    // this is what you want.
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4.landscape,
      ...
    ),
    build: (BuildContext context) => ChildWidget(),
    ...
  ),
)
```

Source: https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/557